# Parent component not being passed to child when "require" is used

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am trying to call functions of a parent component's controller into a child component's controller. However, the parent component does not seem to be injected into my child component's controller on Init.

In the code snippet below I am trying to call the `show` method of my Parent component (i.e. `nvPanel`)'s controller (i.e. `PanelController`) in my child component's controller:

```
module AppExample {
    import ITimeoutService = angular.ITimeoutService;
    import ILogService = angular.ILogService;

    class LegendController implements angular.IComponentController {

        private $timeout: ITimeoutService;
        private $log: ILogService;
        // Parent component reference
        panelComponent: PanelComponent;

        static $inject = [
            "$timeout",
            "$log",
        ];

        constructor(
            $timeout: ITimeoutService,
            $log: ILogService
        ) {
            this.$timeout = $timeout;
            this.$log = $log;
        }

        $onInit(): void {
            let controller = this.panelComponent.controller;
            controller.show();
        }
    }

    class LegendComponent implements angular.IComponentOptions {
        templateUrl = "/.../nv-legend.html";
        controller = LegendController;
        require: {
            panelComponent: "^nvPanel"
        };
    }

    angular.module("AppExample").component("nvLegend", new LegendComponent());
}
```

However, the `panelComponent` is undefined (i.e. not being injected by AngularJS) in the onInit function although it was marked as "required" in the component's options.

This is how the parent and child components are used:

```
<div>
    <nv-panel id="legendPanel">
        ...
        <div id="legend-container" class="slide-out-div">
            <nv-legend></nv-legend>
        </div>
        ...
    </nv-panel>
</div>
```

This is `nv-panel.ts`

```
module AppExample { 
    export class PanelController {

        constructor(...) {
            ...
        }

        show(): void {
            ...
        }     
    }

    export class PanelComponent implements angular.IComponentOptions {
        controller = PanelController;
        templateUrl = "/client/features/shared/panel/nv-panel.html";
        transclude = true;
    }

    angular.module("AppExample").component("nvPanel", new PanelComponent());
```